# Out-File only show last line

Tags: powershell

I'm trying o get `netstat` output in to an out file. The script works well without the `Out-File`, I see everything on the console. However, when I do use `Out-File`, I only see the last line.

```
$ComputerName = Read-Host -Prompt 'Please Input Computer Name'
$cmd = netstat -nao | Select-String "ESTA"
foreach ($element in $cmd) {
  $data = $element -split ' ' | where {$_ -ne ''}
  New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
    'Local IP : Port#'   = $data[1];
    'Remote IP : Port#'  = $data[2];
    'Process ID'         = $data[4];
    'Process Name'       = ((Get-Process | where {$_.ID -eq $data[4]})).Name
    'Process File Path'  = ((Get-Process | where {$_.ID -eq $data[4]})).Path
    'Process Start Time' = ((Get-Process | where {$_.ID -eq $data[4]})).StartTime
    #'Process File Version' = ((Get-Process | where {$_.ID -eq $data[4]})).FileVersion
    'Associated DLLs and File Path' = ((Get-Process | where {$_.ID -eq $data[4]})).Modules |
      select @{Name='Module';Expression={$_.Filename -join ';  '}} |
      Out-File -FilePath c:\temp\net.txt
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Out-File` is in the wrong place. You write just the value that should be assigned to the property `Associated DLLs and File Path` to the output file, and you overwrite the file with each iteration of the loop.

The simple solution is to put `Out-File` *after* the `New-Object` (not inside the property hashtable like you have it now), and add the parameter `-Append`, as [@Esperento57](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40368172/1630171) showed in his answer.

Personally I'd prefer changing the `foreach` to a `ForEach-Object`, though, so you have everything in one pipeline and can output at the end without having to append in a loop. You may also want to avoid enumerating processes repeatedly for several properties.

```
netstat -nao | Select-String 'ESTA' -SimpleMatch | ForEach-Object {
  $data = $_ -split '\s+'
  $proc = Get-Process -Id $data[4]
  New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{
    'Local IP : Port#'   = $data[1];
    'Remote IP : Port#'  = $data[2];
    'Process ID'         = $data[4];
    'Process Name'       = $proc.Name
    'Process File Path'  = $proc.Path
    'Process Start Time' = $proc.StartTime
    #'Process File Version' = $proc.FileVersion
    'Associated DLLs and File Path' = $proc.Modules |
      Select-Ojbect @{Name='Module';Expression={$_.Filename -join ';'}}
  }
} | Set-Content 'C:\temp\net.txt'
```

Answer (score 1):

Note how you're calling `Out-File` *inside a loop*.

Therefore - in the absence of the `-Append` switch - the file gets *rewritten* in every iteration rather than *appended to*.

For a better approach to solving your problem, see [Ansgar Wiechers' helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40368476/45375).

Answer (score 0):

modify like this

```
    $cmd = netstat -nao | select-string "ESTA"
    foreach ($element in $cmd)
    {
    $data = $element -split ' ' | where {$_ -ne ''}
    New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property @{
    'Local IP : Port#'=$data[1];
    'Remote IP : Port#'=$data[2];
    'Process ID'= $data[4];
    'Process Name'=((Get-process |where {$_.ID -eq $data[4]})).Name;
    'Process File Path'=((Get-process |where {$_.ID -eq $data[4]})).path;
    'Process Start Time'=((Get-process |where {$_.ID -eq $data[4]})).starttime;
    #'Process File Version'=((Get-process |where {$_.ID -      eq$data[4]})).FileVersion
    'Associated DLLs and File Path'=((Get-process |where {$_.ID -eq $data[4]})).Modules |select @{Name='Module';Expression={$_.filename -join ';  '} } 
    } |out-file -FilePath c:\temp\net.txt -Append

    }
```